# How to apply filter to the DateSlicer programmatically in C# for the PowerBI Report while exporting to pdf

Tags: c#, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I want to export the power bi report to pdf, to do that I have followed the below article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to

```
Here I'm able to export the report but without data.
So to see the data in the report I have to set the date slicer filter first.
because to see the data there is a dependency on the date slicer filter.

I have tried below code snippets for applying the filter, but nothing worked


//urlFilter = "%2FReportSection%3Ffilter%3DTable%2Fdate%20ge%202021-02-26%20and%20Table%2Fdate%20le%202021-03-02";//not working
//urlFilter = "/ReportSection?filter=DateTable/date ge 2022-05-07 and DateTable/date le 2022-06-07";//not working
//urlFilter = "?filter=DateTable/date ge 2022-05-07 and DateTable/date le 2022-06-07"; //not working
//urlFilter = @"?filter=DateTable/date ge 2022-05-07 and DateTable/date le 2022-06-07";

            var powerBIReportExportConfiguration = new PowerBIReportExportConfiguration
            {
                Settings = new ExportReportSettings
                {
                    Locale = "en-us",
                },
                Pages = new List<ExportReportPage>(),
                ReportLevelFilters = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(urlFilter) ? new List<ExportFilter>() { new ExportFilter(urlFilter) } : null,
            };
```

I really appreciate any help done.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Query String filtering doesn't work with Publish to web or Export to PDF. But You can capture the filters in bookmark and then export the report to pdf.

```
// Capture the Bookmark state 
const capturedBookmark = await report.bookmarksManager.capture();
```

The captured state (which is just a string) is then passed to the PowerBI .NET SDK method `ExportToFileInGroupAsync` as part of the `PowerBIReportExportConfiguration` that is necessary.

References:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to
https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/report-bookmarks
```